# filter Observable ObservableCollection - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
ObservableCollection<Person>  Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(); 

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 1", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email ="abc@abc.com" });  

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 2", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email = "abc@abc.com" });

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 3", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email = "abc@abc.com" }); 

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 4", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email = "abc@abc.com" }); 

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 5", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email = "abc@abc.com" });  

Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "John 6", Age = 25, City = "New Delhi", Email = "abc@abc.com" });

        ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsNew = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

**My question is,**
  `PersonsNew` = skip 3 and Take 4 from `Persons` and Store it in `PersonsNew` as `ObservableCollection<Person>` 
            **but not** as `Var`

**NOTE:**  Read carefully **out put** should be in **`ObservableCollection<Person>`**

**EDIT:**
See, `Persons` ObservableCollection, i have added 6 member in it of Person Class, now i need to have filterd persons from it and store it in new ObservableCollection of Person class say `PersonNew`
Thanks........

Comment: I have no idea what your question is?

Comment: see the Persons ObservableCollection, i have added 6 member in it of Person Class, now i need to have filterd persons from it and store it in new ObservableCollection of Person class say PersonNew    Thanks.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ObservableCollection<Person> PersonsNew = new ObservableCollection<Person>(Persons.Skip(3).Take(4));
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
var PersonsNew = new ObservableCollection<Person>(Persons.Skip(3).Take(4));
```

If you have some criteria by which people can be selected from the Persons collection, you could also use a [collection view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx).

Comment: i think  var PersonsNew = new ObservableCollection<Person>(Persons.Skip(3).Take(4));   it should be ok without var keyword................Thanks.....

Comment: As I said, use of `var` makes the code more succinct - it doesn't change its behavior at all.